# Collection of $_POST data

Tags: php, mvc, laravel, rest

I have a backend API that I'm sure can a refactor, but I'm not exactly sure how to avoid repetition between the `store` method and the `update` method of this controller. Specifically, the collection of `$_POST` data is exactly the same. How can duplication be avoided?

**`store`**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $customer_service = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Customer();

    $input = $request->all();

    $is_same_address = isset($input['customer']['isSameAddress']) ? $input['customer']['isSameAddress'] : '';

    $name = ucwords(strtolower($input['customer']['name']));
    $company = isset($input['customer']['company']) ? $input['customer']['company'] : '';
    $company = ucwords(strtolower($company));
    $primary_phone = isset($input['customer']['primaryPhone']) ? $input['customer']['primaryPhone'] : '';
    $secondary_phone = isset($input['customer']['secondaryPhone']) ? $input['customer']['secondaryPhone'] : '';
    $email = isset($input['customer']['email']) ? $input['customer']['email'] : '';
    $note = isset($input['customer']['note']) ? $input['customer']['note'] : '';
    $ref = isset($input['customer']['ref']) ? $input['customer']['ref'] : '';
    $pickup_city = isset($input['customer']['address']['pickup']['city']) ? $input['customer']['address']['pickup']['city'] : '';
    $pickup_state = isset($input['customer']['address']['pickup']['state']) ? $input['customer']['address']['pickup']['state'] : '';
    $pickup_number = isset($input['customer']['address']['pickup']['number']) ? $input['customer']['address']['pickup']['number'] : '';
    $pickup_suite = isset($input['customer']['address']['pickup']['suite']) ? $input['customer']['address']['pickup']['suite'] : '';
    $pickup_street = isset($input['customer']['address']['pickup']['street']) ? $input['customer']['address']['pickup']['street'] : '';
    $pickup_zip = isset($input['customer']['address']['pickup']['zip']) ? $input['customer']['address']['pickup']['zip'] : '';

    if (empty($pickup_number)) {
        $pickup_line1 = $pickup_street;
    } else {
        $pickup_line1 = $pickup_number . ' ' . $pickup_street;
    }

    if ($is_same_address) {
        $delivery_city = $pickup_city;
        $delivery_state = $pickup_state;
        $delivery_number = $pickup_number;
        $delivery_suite = $pickup_suite;
        $delivery_street = $pickup_street;
        $delivery_zip = $pickup_zip;
        $delivery_line1 = $pickup_number . ' ' . $pickup_street;
    } else {
        $delivery_city = isset($input['customer']['address']['delivery']['city']) ? $input['customer']['address']['delivery']['city'] : '';
        $delivery_state = isset($input['customer']['address']['delivery']['state']) ? $input['customer']['address']['delivery']['state'] : '';
        $delivery_number = isset($input['customer']['address']['delivery']['number']) ? $input['customer']['address']['delivery']['number'] : '';
        $delivery_suite = isset($input['customer']['address']['delivery']['suite']) ? $input['customer']['address']['delivery']['suite'] : '';
        $delivery_street = isset($input['customer']['address']['delivery']['street']) ? $input['customer']['address']['delivery']['street'] : '';
        $delivery_zip = isset($input['customer']['address']['delivery']['zip']) ? $input['customer']['address']['delivery']['zip'] : '';

        if (empty($delivery_number)) {
            $delivery_line1 = $delivery_street;
        } else {
            $delivery_line1 = $delivery_number . ' ' . $delivery_street;
        }
    }
    ...
```

**`update`**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

    $customer_service = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Customer();

    $input = $request->all();

    $is_same_address = isset($input['customer']['isSameAddress']) ? $input['customer']['isSameAddress'] : '';

    $name = isset($input['customer']['updateName']) ? ucwords(strtolower($input['customer']['updateName'])) : '';
    $company = isset($input['customer']['company']) ? $input['customer']['company'] : '';
    $company = ucwords(strtolower($company));
    $primary_phone = isset($input['customer']['primaryPhone']) ? $input['customer']['primaryPhone'] : '';
    $secondary_phone = isset($input['customer']['secondaryPhone']) ? $input['customer']['secondaryPhone'] : '';
    $email = isset($input['customer']['email']) ? $input['customer']['email'] : '';
    $note = isset($input['customer']['note']) ? $input['customer']['note'] : '';
    $ref = isset($input['customer']['ref']) ? $input['customer']['ref'] : '';
    $pickup_city = isset($input['customer']['address']['pickup']['city']) ? $input['customer']['address']['pickup']['city'] : '';
    $pickup_state = isset($input['customer']['address']['pickup']['state']) ? $input['customer']['address']['pickup']['state'] : '';
    $pickup_number = isset($input['customer']['address']['pickup']['number']) ? $input['customer']['address']['pickup']['number'] : '';
    $pickup_suite = isset($input['customer']['address']['pickup']['suite']) ? $input['customer']['address']['pickup']['suite'] : '';
    $pickup_street = isset($input['customer']['address']['pickup']['street']) ? $input['customer']['address']['pickup']['street'] : '';
    $pickup_zip = isset($input['customer']['address']['pickup']['zip']) ? $input['customer']['address']['pickup']['zip'] : '';

    if ($pickup_number) {
        $pickup_line1 = $pickup_number . ' ' . $pickup_street;
    } else {
        $pickup_line1 = $pickup_street;
    }

    if ($is_same_address) {
        $delivery_city = $pickup_city;
        $delivery_state = $pickup_state;
        $delivery_number = $pickup_number;
        $delivery_suite = $pickup_suite;
        $delivery_street = $pickup_street;
        $delivery_zip = $pickup_zip;
        $delivery_line1 = $pickup_line1;
    } else {
        $delivery_city = isset($input['customer']['address']['delivery']['city']) ? $input['customer']['address']['delivery']['city'] : '';
        $delivery_state = isset($input['customer']['address']['delivery']['state']) ? $input['customer']['address']['delivery']['state'] : '';
        $delivery_number = isset($input['customer']['address']['delivery']['number']) ? $input['customer']['address']['delivery']['number'] : '';
        $delivery_suite = isset($input['customer']['address']['delivery']['suite']) ? $input['customer']['address']['delivery']['suite'] : '';
        $delivery_street = isset($input['customer']['address']['delivery']['street']) ? $input['customer']['address']['delivery']['street'] : '';
        $delivery_zip = isset($input['customer']['address']['delivery']['zip']) ? $input['customer']['address']['delivery']['zip'] : '';


        if ($delivery_number) {
            $delivery_line1 = $delivery_number . ' ' . $delivery_street;
        } else {
            $delivery_line1 = $delivery_street;
        }

    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to go the OOP way and create a class which has all those fields as members. Then you do the initialization once and let the member functions just use the fields. This nicely avoids the code duplication and opens up opportunities for better design in general.

Also the local variable `$pickup_line1` doesn't seem to be used in `store()` is this correct?

If you don't want to go the OOP way you can extract a function like this:

```
public function write(Request $request, String $pickup_line1, String $delivery_line1) {
    $customer_service = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Customer();

    $input = $request->all();

    $is_same_address = isset($input['customer']['isSameAddress']) ? $input['customer']['isSameAddress'] : '';

    $name = ucwords(strtolower($input['customer']['name']));
    $company = isset($input['customer']['company']) ? $input['customer']['company'] : '';
    $company = ucwords(strtolower($company));
    $primary_phone = isset($input['customer']['primaryPhone']) ? $input['customer']['primaryPhone'] : '';
    $secondary_phone = isset($input['customer']['secondaryPhone']) ? $input['customer']['secondaryPhone'] : '';
    $email = isset($input['customer']['email']) ? $input['customer']['email'] : '';
    $note = isset($input['customer']['note']) ? $input['customer']['note'] : '';
    $ref = isset($input['customer']['ref']) ? $input['customer']['ref'] : '';
    $pickup_city = isset($input['customer']['address']['pickup']['city']) ? $input['customer']['address']['pickup']['city'] : '';
    $pickup_state = isset($input['customer']['address']['pickup']['state']) ? $input['customer']['address']['pickup']['state'] : '';
    $pickup_number = isset($input['customer']['address']['pickup']['number']) ? $input['customer']['address']['pickup']['number'] : '';
    $pickup_suite = isset($input['customer']['address']['pickup']['suite']) ? $input['customer']['address']['pickup']['suite'] : '';
    $pickup_street = isset($input['customer']['address']['pickup']['street']) ? $input['customer']['address']['pickup']['street'] : '';
    $pickup_zip = isset($input['customer']['address']['pickup']['zip']) ? $input['customer']['address']['pickup']['zip'] : '';

    if ($is_same_address) {
        $delivery_city = $pickup_city;
        $delivery_state = $pickup_state;
        $delivery_number = $pickup_number;
        $delivery_suite = $pickup_suite;
        $delivery_street = $pickup_street;
        $delivery_zip = $pickup_zip;
    } else {
        $delivery_city = isset($input['customer']['address']['delivery']['city']) ? $input['customer']['address']['delivery']['city'] : '';
        $delivery_state = isset($input['customer']['address']['delivery']['state']) ? $input['customer']['address']['delivery']['state'] : '';
        $delivery_number = isset($input['customer']['address']['delivery']['number']) ? $input['customer']['address']['delivery']['number'] : '';
        $delivery_suite = isset($input['customer']['address']['delivery']['suite']) ? $input['customer']['address']['delivery']['suite'] : '';
        $delivery_street = isset($input['customer']['address']['delivery']['street']) ? $input['customer']['address']['delivery']['street'] : '';
        $delivery_zip = isset($input['customer']['address']['delivery']['zip']) ? $input['customer']['address']['delivery']['zip'] : '';
    }
    ...
```

Then in `store` and `update` just do the minimum code necessary to calculate the `$pickup_line` and `$delivery_line1` and call `write`.

*Pardon my rusty PHP.*

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure if attributes was the way to since they would only be fore the store and update methods.  But now, it makes sense.

Comment: You can make a special class with only the attributes that you create an instance of when you need the attributes parsed.